# How can I install more than one version of the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, osx-snow-leopard, ios4

I want to install the iPhone 4.0 SDK, but I don't want to lose my stable 3.2 version because I am planning on packaging an app for distribution soon.  Any tips on installing more than one version?

Snow leopard 10.6.3
X Code 3.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can...When you are at the "Installation Type" pane in the installer you can click then "Location" folder and create a new one to install into, ie `/DeveloperBeta`

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100203-ny1ahei187k36t1aihf8k97crs.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100203-ny1ahei187k36t1aihf8k97crs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the way the SDKs are deployed you are allowed to specify a target directory at the time of install. This should give you the ability to install the beta SDK and leave your stable one untouched at the same time.

Comment: It only lets me select my hard-drive, no sub-folders etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I've seen is to rename your existing 'Developer' folder to say 'DeveloperStable', then run the beta installer and have it install to 'Developer' again.  You then can rename the newly installed beta.  This is how you can install several SDKs at once.  Burns a lot of HD space, but these days HDs are cheap anyway.